# Select where date between given month and day of any year in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two dates and I want to make a SELECT statement based on the dates. Let's say the dates are `2019-09-14` to `2019-10-15`.

I know that I can do the following

`SELECT date, amount, name FROM table WHERE name IN ('a', 'b') AND date BETWEEN '2019-09-14' AND '2019-10-15'`.

What should I do if I want to instead select all records between Sept 14 to Oct 15 regardless of the year?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using simple arithmetics:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
    name in ('a', 'b')
    and extract(month from date) * 100 + extract(day from date) between 914 and 1015
```

The idea is to extract separately the month and day, and compare them against a range of numbers. You can also format the date and do string comparison:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
    name in ('a', 'b')
    and format_date('%m%d', date) between '0914' and '1015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select date, amount, name 
from table 
where name in ('a', 'b') 
and date between date(extract(year from date), 9, 14) and date(extract(year from date), 10, 15)
```

or little less verbose and bigquery'ish version of above

```
select date, amount, name 
from table, unnest([extract(year from date)]) year 
where name in ('a', 'b') 
and date between date(year, 9, 14) and date(year, 10, 15)
```